# Typescript Unit Test Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm newbie in both typescript and jest. And follow [this](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/testing/jest.html) tutorial but not sure why it prompt error for this simple code when i try, anyone could give some advise?

> Unexpected token, expected "," (1:21)
>
> ```
> > 1 | export const sum = (a: number) =>  a;
>     |                      ^
> ```

**Code**

foo.ts

```
export const sum = (a: number) =>  a;
```

foo.test.ts

```
import  {sum}  from '../src/foo';

test('basic', () => {
  expect(sum(1)).toBe(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of the **jest.config.js** need to be same level on the rest of the *.config
 [image]